# Alfresco и MS Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, web-apps, ldap

Установил последний  Alfresco Community v5.2.0, пытаюсь настроить аутентификацию пользователей из АД (win 2008r2).

домен - proektng.local
контроллер - dc01.proektng.local
все пользователи в группе - user и далее по подгруппам

Не получается, что сделано:

в АД создал пользователя user_alfresco@proektng.local
права "Read all inetOrgPerson information"
пароль - 12345678

в файл

```
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties
```

в конец добавил строчку:

```
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm:alfrescoNtlm,ldap-ad:ldap-ad
```

создал папки и файлы которых не было

```
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap-ad-authentication.properties
```

содержимое файла:

```
ldap.authentication.active=true
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=true
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@proektng.local
ldap.authentication.java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://dc01.proektng.local:389
ldap.authentication.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInBind=false
ldap.authentication.escapeCommasInUid=false
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=Administrator,admin
ldap.synchronization.active=true
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.authentication=simple
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=user_alfresco@proektng.local
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=12345678
ldap.synchronization.queryBatchSize=1000
ldap.synchronization.attributeBatchSize=1000
ldap.synchronization.groupQuery=(objectclass\=group)
ldap.synchronization.groupDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=group)(!(modifyTimestamp<\={0})))
ldap.synchronization.personQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512))
ldap.synchronization.personDifferentialQuery=(&(objectclass\=user)(userAccountControl\:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803\:\=512)(!$
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou\=user,dc=proektng,dc=local
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou\=user,dc=proektng,dc=local
ldap.synchronization.modifyTimestampAttributeName=modifyTimestamp
ldap.synchronization.timestampFormat=yyyyMMddHHmmss'.0Z'
ldap.synchronization.userIdAttributeName=sAMAccountName
ldap.synchronization.userFirstNameAttributeName=givenName
ldap.synchronization.userLastNameAttributeName=sn
ldap.synchronization.userEmailAttributeName=mail
```

Comment: Почитайте про WMI, а имеено как прочесть Active Directory через WMI. Как я понял вопрос прочесть AD.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052695/c-sharp-active-directory-via-wmi http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392320(v=VS.85).aspx
http://www.winfrastructure.net/article.aspx?BlogEntry=Get-Active-Directory-users-using-WMI

Comment: Хм.. А вопрос-то где?

Answer (score 1):

Была та же самая проблема. Если в конец файла

```
/alfresco/tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties
```

добавить

```
authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap-ad
ntlm.authentication.sso.enabled=false
ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin=false
ldap.authentication.userNameFormat=%s@domain.com
ldap.authentication.java.naming.provider.url=ldap://dcxxx.domain.com:389
ldap.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=AdminAlf
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.principal=AlfLdapReader@office.local
ldap.synchronization.java.naming.security.credentials=alfalf
ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=ou=Groups,ou=City-OU,dc=domain,dc=com
ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=ou=Users,ou=City-OU,dc=domain,dc=com
```

То доменная авторизация начинает работать. При этом при синхронизации вываливает ошибку.

У тебя же ошибка в том что ты неправильно создал папки.

Папка ***ldap-ad*** здесь название общей папки подсистемы аутентификации ldap-ad.

```
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/***ldap-ad***/ldap-ad-authentication.properties
```

Но папки с настройками имя которой ты указываешь здесь

```
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm:alfrescoNtlm,***ldap-ad***:ldap-ad
```

У тебя не существует.
В итоге чтобы у тебя заработала аутентификация нужно создать папку ldap-ad по пути

```
/opt/alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/
```

И уже в нее перенести файл

```
ldap-ad-authentication.properties
```

P.S Я здесь новичок если и есть какие ошибки прошу ткнуть носом)